# Matching alphabetical characters with Java Regex which are not preceded by percent sign

Tags: java, regex, string

### tl;dr:

I want to take a string like: `ab%cde%fg hij %klm n%op`

And convert it to any of (all are acceptable):

- `'ab'%c'de'%f'g hij '%k'lm n'%o'p'`
- `'ab'%c'de'%f'g' 'hij' %k'lm' 'n'%o'p'`
- `'a''b'%c'd''e'%f'g' 'h''i''j' %k'l''m' 'n'%o'p'`

(if an alphabetical character is not preceded by a `%`, it needs to be within single quotes. Opening and closing extra single quotes is acceptable)

### Use Case

I'm trying to take a string in [C `strftime` format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) and convert it to work with Java's `SimpleDateFormat`. For the most part, this is pretty straight forward:

```
String format = "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";

Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("%a", "EEE");
    put("%A", "EEEE");
    put("%b", "MMM");
    put("%B", "MMMM");
    put("%c", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy");
    // ... for each strftime token, create a mapping ...
}};

for ( String key : replacements.keySet() )
{
    // apply the mappings one at a time
    format = format.replaceAll(key, replacements.get(key));
}

// Then format
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

However when I introduce character literals, it runs into issues. According to the `strftime` documentation, ***all*** character literal not preceded by a percent sign are passed along without modification to the output string. So:

```
Format: "%y is a great year!"
Output: "2019 is a great year!"
```

However with `SimpleDateFormat`, all character literals are treated as tokens unless surrounded by single quotes:

```
Format: "yyyy 'is a great year!'"
Output: "2019 is a great year!"

Format: "yyyy is a great year!"
Output: ERROR - invalid token "i"
```

### Desired Output

Because `strftime` tokens are always a ***single character***, it shouldn't be too difficult to fix our format string. In a worst case scenario, "if a letter is not preceded by a `%` sign, wrap it in single quotes", which would lead to:

```
Format: "%y is a great year!"
Processed: "%y 'i''s' 'a' 'g''r''e''a''t' 'y''e''a''r'!"
```

This is ugly, but would behave as expected and is an acceptable answer. Ideally we would wrap ***all runs of alphabetical characters not preceded by a `%`***, like so:

```
Format: "%y is a great year!"
Processed: "%y 'is' 'a' 'great' 'year'!"
```

Or, better yet, all runs ***including non-alpha and non-`%` characters***:

```
Format: "%y is a great year!"
Processed: "%y' is a great year!'"
```

### What I've tried

I started with a mindless regular expression that I was pretty sure wouldn't work, and it didn't:

```
format.replaceAll("[^%]([a-zA-Z]+)", "'$1'");
// Format:   "Literal %t Literal"
// Output:   "'iteral' %t'Literal'"
// Expected: "'Literal' %t 'Literal'"
```

I don't have a firm grasp on back-references so I gave them a whirl but messed something up there as well:

```
format.replaceAll("(?!%)([a-zA-Z]+)", "'$1'");
// Format:   "Literal %t Literal"
// Output:   "'Literal' %'t' 'Literal'"
// Expected: "'Literal' %t 'Literal'"
```

I also considered writing a ***very*** simple lexer. Something like:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
boolean inQuote = false;
for (int i = 0; i < format.length; i++)
{
    if (format[i] == '%')
    {
        i++;
        s.append(replacements.get(format[i]);
    }
    else if (inQuote)
    {
        s.append(format[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        s.append("'");
        inQuote = true;
        s.append(format[i]);
    }
}
```

However I learned that `format[i]` isn't valid Java syntax, and didn't spend much time looking into how to properly get a character from a string before I decided to just post here.

I would prefer a regular expression solution so that I can write it in a single line instead of a loop like this.

Comment: I'd think this would be easier without regex. Basically a loop of "if next char is %, skip that + one more", repeat, when not %, add a single quote, close at either end of string or next % sign. Loop and repeat.

Comment: "*didn't spend much time looking into how to properly get a character from a string before I decided to just post here*" - Please use Stack Overflow as a last resort, once you've exhausted all your current research options. You can create a `char[]` from the string which you can iterate over via `String#toCharArray()`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I know that I can use StackOverflow (or just Google) to find answers to questions. Yesterday evening, curious how to do it, I looked up the java docs and found `String.charAt()` which worked perfectly for my purposes. The reason I didn't put any effort into building the lexer is because the lexer solution was 20+ lines of code that were hard to follow. If I could do the same with a regular expression, I could write less and it'd be easier to follow. Hence why a regular expression was preferred.

Comment: Try `s="'" + s.replaceAll("%[a-z]", "'$0'") + "'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been updated to work with a single regex.  Additional formats can be added to test for correctness.

```java
      String[] formats = { "ab%cde%fg hij %klm n%op", "ab%c", "%d"
      };
      for (String f : formats) {
         String parsed = f.replaceAll("(^[a-z]+|(?<=%[a-z])([a-z ]+))", "'$1'");
         System.out.println(parsed);
      }
```

The two possibilities are:

- Put all characters `[a-z]+` that follow `%[a-z]` between single quotes.
- Place any characters that precede `%` and not included above between
  single quotes.

Comment: While a bit awkward (`%a` becomes `''%a''`), it fits the requirements and seems like it will work. I'll quickly verify with my handful of test strings in my app.

Comment: Well it seems to meet the specific requirements laid out (letters preceded by a `%` are not quoted), but it ended up failing with regards to my actual use case as described in the question. It turns out that two single in a row is treated by `SimpleDateFormat` as a single quote in the output, so `%a` -> `''%a''` -> `'Thu'` (expected just `Thu` without the quotes)

Comment: Because it meets the requirements as laid out, I'll amend the question this evening when I have time (I need to run right now) so I can accept this as it at least taught me a new way to use regular expressions, and for now I'll focus on my lexer solution

Comment: One additional modification I might make to the answer is replacing `[a-z]` with `[a-zA-Z]` to catch capital letters, as well. Otherwise, this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Why not use several replaceAll functions since you have already considered it.

> First, add single quotes to all consecutive character strings;
>
> Then, move the single quote preceded by % by one character;
>
> Last, remove empty quotes.

Below is my testing code in Python. I believe it works in other languages such as Java as well.

```
>>> str1=re.sub("([a-zA-Z]+)","'\g<1>'",input)
>>> str2=re.sub("%'([a-zA-Z])'","%\g<1>",str1)
>>> str3=re.sub("''","",str2)
>>> str1
"'Literal' %'t' 'Literal'"
>>> str2
"'Literal' %t 'Literal'"
>>> str3
"'Literal' %t 'Literal'"
```